# Calculating distance from line to multiple points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, proximity

I have road maps (line features) and point features representing forest plots. I created buffer around the roads. Now I want to know the distance from line(road) to the points within this buffer.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have advanced license? If yes, you need the tool Generate Near Table. Also, please provide some more detail regarding your problem and what you have tried so far. Why did you create the buffers?

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't have advanced but do have 3D Analyst, you can use Near3D

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using Python and arcpy, you could use a cursor to iterate through the point features, extracting the geometry for each of them in turn.

For each point geometry, you can pass it to the line geometry's `angleAndDistanceTo()` method, which returns an angle and the distance to the passed in point geometry.

See:

- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/polyline.htm
- http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm

(UPDATE:  Actually, I'm unsure if a line's `angleAndDistanceTo()` method uses the nearest point on the line to measure the distance to, or if it uses some other point on the line.  It would need some testing or further research.)